# Algebraic Structures that are similar to Vector Spaces but exist over a Commutative Ring as opposed to a Field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, field-theory

I was just wondering if there are Vector Space 'like' structures in which instead of existing over a Field exist over a Commutative Ring?

Thanks, David

Comment: You're welcome
$$\textrm{}$$
-David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists the notion of a *module* over a ring, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Module.html.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem! I hope this helps.

Comment: The field that covers the study of modules over commutative rings is called commutative algebra.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - Thanks for that :-)